# ambiguous tag: [tag:silo]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, ambiguous-tags

Recently I stumbled upon [silo](/questions/tagged/silo) and found out it has ambiguous meaning.
Is it possible to create unambiguous tags instead?

Comment: Given that splitting it up would seem to result in tags with just a single question, I wonder if it's needed at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There seems to be two question **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5969828/compound-datatypes-with-h5py-datatype-inside-an-attribute)** and **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201458/visualizing-a-structured-mesh-containing-odd-shaped-elements)** that's actually a valid use for that tag.

Actually scratch that, there's **[another valid use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13123465/php-organizing-keywords-in-silo-seo-structure)**, but on a different topic (but it's closed).

It seems that SILO refers to two things: A third party scientific I/O library and an SEO pattern.

On that basis, I'd say that it probably should be expanded to refer to the I/O library, whilst the other question to be de-tagged as SILO (question maybe even deleted as it's already closed).

Comment: I removed the tag from the one where it was obviously misused; I'll leave rewriting the tag wiki to cover only the mesh library to someone who's actually familiar with it, if that's the consensus.